# How to apply CSS to second word in a string?

Tags: css

If I have the following string: John Smith, how could I use CSS to set `font-weight: bold` on the second word in order to achieve: John **Smith**.

Can this be done in pure CSS?

*Update*: I am retrieving user's name from the server, so in my template it is `#{user.profile.name}`.

Comment: Nope :( http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

Comment: @KrishR I think they want this to be done automatically. It does have a css tag.

Comment: No way to do this with pure CSS, I'm afraid, but if you don't mind using a little JavaScript, you can try something like: http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/p5g5b/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a js solution was suggested and pure CSS isn't presently possible: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/ANIPImO/6/edit)**

**Sample markup:**

```
<p class="bold-second-word">John Smith</p>
<p class="bold-second-word">This guy and stuff.</p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var toBold = document.getElementsByClassName('bold-second-word');
for (var i=0; i<toBold.length; ++i) {
  boldSecondWord(toBold[i]);
}

function boldSecondWord(elem) {
  elem.innerHTML = elem.textContent.replace(/\w+ (\w+)/, function(s, c) {
    return s.replace(c, '<b>'+c+'</b>');
  });
}
```

Comment: OK, you've got the better solution, I must admit. But it *was* a yes/no question...

Comment: This solution was perfect for me when I wanted to alter the 'Sold out' badge to a 'Sold' badge on a WooCommerce site. By replacing the <b> tags with <span> I could target the word 'out' and set it to display:none. This has saved me faffing about with extra plugins or editing functions.php files.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done in pure CSS, sorry. But if you are willing to accept a JavaScript fix, then you might want to look into something like this:

- Find the start and end index of the second word in the element's `textContent`.
- Add `contenteditable` attribute to element.
- Use the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) to select that range.
- Use [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands) with the `bold` command.
- Remove `contenteditable` attribute.

EDIT: (just saw your edit) I agree this is a bit too hack-y for most uses. Perhaps you'd be better off saving what the last name is as meta-data?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be impossible by using only pure CSS. However, with a bit of JS you could get there pretty easily:

```js
const phrases = document.querySelectorAll('.bold-second-word');
for (const phrase of phrases) {
  const words = phrase.innerHTML.split(' ');
  words[1] = `<b>${words[1]}</b>`; // this would return the second word
  phrase.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
}
```

```html
<p class="bold-second-word">John Smith</p>
<p class="bold-second-word">Aaron Kelly Jones</p>
```